# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip' how to solve?

Tags: python, api, discord, bots, strip

Hello i cant figure out why i get this error :/

full code:

```py
import discord
import os

client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content.startswith('$hello'):
        await message.channel.send('Hello!')

client.run(os.getenv('discord api'))
```

full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thoma\Documents\discordbot\bot.py", line 18, in <module>
    client.run(os.getenv('NzkzNzczNDUwODQ5NDE5Mjk2.X-xJIg.MoKUA7czhrWtFvu4FEc6M3JAQQM'))
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 708, in run
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 687, in runner
    await self.start(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 650, in start
    await self.login(*args, bot=bot)
  File "C:\Users\thoma\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 499, in login
    await self.http.static_login(token.strip(), bot=bot)
```

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: Can you share the full traceback?

Comment: If that's your Discord token, you NEED to regenerate it or anyone will be able to modify your bot's behavior (which can mean banning everyone in the bots' servers, or deleting every message, for example)

Comment: Also, edit history is public on StackOverflow. Anyone can still see your token in the history, and that means you should still regenerate it.

Comment: Finally, it's most likely because `os.getenv()` returns `None`, hence you're not feeding any token to your discord client. To fetch environment variables, you need to refer to their names, not their values. For example, `os.getenv(DISCORD_TOKEN)` if you named it like this.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it like this

1. Install "pip install python-dotenv"
2. Put this in your code:

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), '.env'))
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv("TOKEN")
client.run(SECRET_KEY)
```

Answer (score 0):

I added `strip()` to the wrong method (.append() instead of the str())

```
ingredients.append(str(table_row)).strip('\(')
```

Fixed that way:

```
ingredients.append(str(table_row).strip('\('))
```

Comment: `str(object)`  is what I needed, thanks!